# How many layouts can I work with?

Tags: android-layout

Iam new to android development and I have a simple question about layouts.
If I want to create something like a text based game. Like there is a paragraph of text and some buttons that move to different pages.
How do I make it work?
my idea is to create A LOT of layouts. Because the text and buttons below it will change with every page.
but can I do that? Wont too many layouts take too much ram memory or something like that?
Can I get away with like **200** layouts?
It would be very easy to work with like that.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, a layout file is not a good choice for describing a game's logic.

Maybe you only need one layout for your app (basically you only described one screen) and fill it with different data (the text can also be set dynamically).

For *scripting* the game, you could invent a simple file format (maybe also xml, if you like that) and define your game's screens and the connection between them there.

If all the screens you want to implement only differ in some buttons, it is usually not worth to create a separate layout for every screen. You can change the visibility of buttons with View's `setVisibility(int)` method and set different OnClickListeners to lead to other screens.

You can also investigate in reusing and including layouts:
http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

and ViewStubs:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html